# Don't repeat the DAO! Using the generic DAO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics

I've been trying to create a generic DAO by following this:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html

I'm stuck on the actual use of it, though. There's a line that looks like this:

```
GenericDao dao = (GenericDao);
```

I don't understand what is going on here, mostly on the right-hand side of the equation. Eclipse is giving me two markers on this line:

> GenericDao is a raw type and should be parameterized. (This is on the GenericDao on the left)
>
> GenericDao cannot be resolved to a variable. (This on the GenericDao on the right)

I've never seen a class/interface name in parentheses all by itself on the right side of an assignment, so I'm not sure what to make of it. An explanation of what is going on in this line so that I can figure out what I should be doing with it to make it work would be very much appreciated.

(Using Eclipse Kepler, Hibernate 4.3.5, Spring IDE 3.5, M2E 1.4.1 if any of that makes any difference)

Comment: You added the `;` on your own

Comment: If you're ok with spring and hibernate, try spring-data jpa. Making your own generic daos for JPA entities is not anything you need to mess with anymore.

Comment: @NathanHughes I'm not super-familiar with Spring. I'm trying to learn it in combination with Hibernate while I'm waiting to start my new job. My team gave me a lot of reading about the tech we'll be using (Spring and Hibernate included), but just reading about it wasn't working for me. I'm trying to put some fairly simple projects together so I have at least some clue how these things work when I start. I'll try looking up the spring-data jpa, thanks!

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Oh man, I feel dumb. Java habit of putting the ; at the end of a line!

Comment: here's an answer i wrote describing the basics of spring-data jpa http://stackoverflow.com/a/15573461/217324 just to give you an idea.

Comment: @NathanHughes So I've been looking into spring-data jpa and it sounds pretty awesome. Can you tell me how Hibernate fits in with it?

Comment: @Tajha: hibernate implements the jpa spec. spring data works with any jpa implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code sample given, there is a line break there. The line should read as
`GenericDao dao = (GenericDao) beanFactory.getBean("personDao");` and to fix the error about a raw type, change it to `GenericDao<Person,Long> dao = (GenericDao<Person, Long>) beanFactory.getBean("personDao");` or something close to that, assuming that the type of the primary key is a Long

Comment: You mean PK? I assumed it meant Primary Key, but I haven't actually been able to find it anywhere.... I could be completely wrong, though.

Comment: That's probably it. Thanks.

Comment: How to do the same in spring boot without JPA ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole line in your example is

```
 GenericDao dao = (GenericDao)beanFactory.getBean("personDao");
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct line of code:

```
GenericDao dao = (GenericDao)
 beanFactory.getBean("personDao"); // This should normally be injected
```