# Retrieve without using the id in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table:

```
User: id, name, age, role_key
```

where Id is the unique identifier.
I want to retrieve all the users with a particular role_key.

I could do something like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT u From user WHERE user.role_key LIKE :roleKey")
    .setParameter("roleKey", roleKey)
    .getResultList();
```

But I wanted to know if there is a better way to write the query. 
For example, if I wanted to retrieve by just using Id, I could have used `find`. But, since I am using role_key which is not unique, is there a way that I need not write the complete select query here.

Thanks

Comment: Define "better"! - Where do you see problems with what you have?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "better way"? Table design, query design?

Comment: try spring data jpa

Comment: If you want to get all "users" (plural) you shouldn't use `getSingleResult()` but rather `getResultList()` to get more than one result.

Comment: Generally equality checks are more performant than `LIKE` clauses. Also make sure that you have an index on `role_key`. Those are probably the biggest two things to think about.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify it

Comment: After your edit I second @farrellmr: Take a look at [Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571608/using-spring-data-to-implement-dao).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Spring Data

Comment: @slal if adding megabytes of libraries just to obfuscate a single query is "better" in your book (e.g. you are paid by megabyte of dependencies of for finding obscure bugs) - then go with spring data. If you like indexes that slow down insertions, bloat database and are not used during queries - add an index to role_key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to JonK's comment, I will advise you use @NamedQuery for performance gain since your query is a parameterized query.
I'm sorry this should have come as a comment but my rep. won't permit me.